# C# structure of generic factory for multiple derived classes

Tags: c#, oop, generics

Consider the following situation:

There can be `Categories`; `Children` derived from `Categories`; and somewhere, there must be a method that looks like:

```
ChildType[] Get(ParentType parent) { ... }
```

`ChildType` is not derived from `ParentType`; they are so-named because this method is a factory method for getting children based on the ID of the parent.

Currently I have something that looks like this:

```
static class CatFactory<ChildType, ParentType> : Category
    where ParentType: Category
    where ChildType: Category, new()
{
    public static ChildType[] Get(string catname, ParentType parent)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class ParentCategoryA : Category { }

class ParentCategoryB: Category { }

class ChildCategoryA: Category { }

class ChildCategoryB: Category { }
```

And then I would call the factory like this:

```
CatFactory<ChildCategoryA, ParentCategoryA>.Get(someparent);
```

The intent of this is - given some strongly-typed parent instance with an ID, go to a web service with that ID and then deserialize a new child instance.

This leaves a bad taste in my mouth. It seems to me that `ChildCategoryA` should know that its parent is `ParentCategoryA`, and one should be able to call `ChildCategoryA.Get(someparent)`. This is of course possible by defining a `static Get()` for each implementation of a child, but that would require a large amount of repetitive code.

So - what's the best way to do this? Separate factory class, or no?

Comment: Can you define a generic `Category<TParentType>`? So you would have `class ChildCategoryA : Category<ParentCategoryA>`? (in turn, `Category<TParentType>` _might_ inherit from a non-generic `Category` base class if it makes sense for your API)

Comment: There can't be a `Category<TParentType>`, because some categories have no parents. I could, however, have something like `ChildCategory<TParentType>`. But I don't know how far that would get me - how would I have a single `static Get()`?

Comment: You can define a sealed, internal constructor `RootCategory` type to serve as a dummy to indicate a root category. As for the `Get`... uhhhh well types could register themselves on first usage (static constructor)? Or you can do a search via reflection on application startup to find all types?

Comment: I think `public static ChildType[] Get(string catname)` would be a cleaner signature. The `ParentType` would be inferred from the `CatFactory`'s type. (I don't have a compiler handy to test this.)

Comment: @neontapir `Get()` needs to be passed a parent instance to get a child. It doesn't only depend on the type of the parent, but the value of one of the parent's fields.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I don't completely follow the static constructor / reflection suggestion - could you expand on that in an answer?

Comment: @Reinderien When I have time tonight at home I can whip something up (just finished my lunch break at work). If possible, could you maybe post sample code of how you exactly intend to consume/work with this? I'm not entirely sure exactly what you're trying to do either! (are you using the `CatFactory` to create instances of `TChildType` which are attached to instances of `TParentType`?)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Almost. Will update question.

Comment: Are you sure that the factory pattern is appropriate here?  It's a little weird that your "factory" creates objects of a specified type.  Usually, you use the factory pattern when you don't want to reveal the concrete type of the objects created.

Comment: @PeterRuderman I'm not sure - do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @Reinderien Me again. Still not sure exactly what the requirements are. Do you expect that for any given ParentType, it will have only one ChildType associated with it? Or the other way around, for any given ChildType will it only be associated with a single ParentType? Or is it both? Because from the sounds of it, it sounds like your input is a strongly typed parent, from which you should know at compile-time what children type you're getting. I don't see the requirement necessarily that a child knows its parent type. If you want both to know each other, I'll see what to do.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair "Do you expect that for any given ParentType, it will have only one ChildType associated with it?" No. "Or the other way around, for any given ChildType will it only be associated with a single ParentType?" Yes.

Comment: @Reinderien So, what you need is "Given some `TParentType` parent object, give me all children of it that are compatible with an arbitrary `TChildType`. In addition, my code should be compile-time validated such that `TChildType` is associated with `TParentType`; that I cannot pass in an instance of `TOtherParentType`. *In addition*, some `TChildType` types have no associated `TParentType`."? (the last requirement is coming from your first comment in this thread) Is this correct?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Very close. I really just need to get one child at a time; getting all of them would be network-expensive. So more like: Given some `TParentType` parent object and a `TChildType` whose parent type is a `TParentType`, give me the corresponding child. In addition, my code should be compile-time validated such that `TChildType` is associated with `TParentType`; that I cannot pass in an instance of `TOtherParentType`. You can drop the last part - it's more like 'some categories are parents only, and not children'.

Answer (score 3):

I find this question a little confusing.  This is what I think you want to do:

Write a static method that, given a Category object, knows how to find all the children of that category of a specified type.

If that's correct, then I would suggest an extension method:

```
static class CategoryExtensions
{
    public static T[] GetChildren<T>(this Category parent)
        where T : Category, new()
    {
        // Do whatever...
    }
}
```

Then, given any category object, you can write:

```
ChildCategory[] children = parent.GetChildren<ChildCategory>();
```

Comment: But then you can call parent.GetChildren<ChildCategoryB>() on a parent instance of type ParentCategoryA even if there exists no situation where this child class is associated with such a parent. Maybe the semantic could be to just not return anything in this case but maybe the developer wants to get a compile-time error.

Comment: That's certainly possible.  I did say that the question was confusing. ;)  Given the code sample in the OP, however, it appears that he wants to define the GetChildren() operation over arbitrary pairs of types.

Comment: In the ideal situation, arbitrary pair types shouldn't be supported, because given a certain child, it only has one valid parent type.

Comment: @PeterRuderman If it is possible to do as CSharper suggests and get a compile-time error on a type pair mismatch - do you have any suggestions to go about doing this?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but at this point we're starting to talk about a more fundamental redesign.  It's hard to know what to advise without understanding what you're trying to achieve in detail.  Is there some reason you aren't using a framework like WCF?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use reflection to locate the required types at runtime.  This is slow and not generally recommended; if you do, it's wise to cache the results so as to avoid reflecting multiple times.

An alternative that doesn't involve reflection is for children to add themselves to a registry of some sort in static initializers - that way you can trivially write the `Get<TChild, TParent>` method you want while keeping knowledge of relationships "local".

Personally, if all such relationships were known at compile-time I'd just wire them all up in one place and save myself the trouble of remembering where everything is defined. =)